# Unable to boot Windows 10 after deleting and formating Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows

Tags: windows-10, grub, ubuntu-14.04

Right now I'm stuck in grub rescue. I have no idea about it. I've tried anything that I found on this site and on the web. Nothing works.

I've tried booting ubuntu from usb using pendrive, didn't work.

Is there any way I can boot to Windows again? I don't mind if I had to format everything. I don't have my Windows installation disk.

here is my ls

```
(hd0) (hd0, msdos3) (hd0, msdos2) (hd0, msdos1)
```

here is my set

```
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0, msdos3)/boot/grub root=hd0, msdos3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. What I did was, I downloaded Ubuntu and made a bootable USB Stick, booted from the Stick and chose "Test from Live CD". Then I plugged in another Hard Drive and mounted the Windows Partition and the external Hard Drive in /mnt after becoming root in the Terminal. Then I copied my User folder to the external Hard drive and formatted my internal Hard Drive and Installed Windows again. When the installation is done you can retransfer your data. They are other solutions, but they did not work for me, and if they don't work for you, try mine.

Comment: Actually, I already tried to do that. It didn't work. I cannot boot ubuntu from usb

Comment: go to my account and on the elementary OS stack exchange have A look at the "Grub Rescue Madness" post maby there is A solution somewhere for you